# can i assume-role over an aws ec2 instance-profile with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i am running into a situation where i am trying to run a terraform (`v0.11.7`) script within jenkins within kubernetes (k8s) within an ec2-instance.

- the k8s worker is running on an ec2-instance with a particular aws instance-profile
- the terraform script is configured via various environment variables, credentials 
  and config files to be able to assume a specific role for it's purposes

the setup works fine on my macbook, but sadly, in jenkins/k8s/ec2, the ec2 instance-profile is prevailing and the terraform script is failing because it requires it's specific assume-role to complete it's operations.

it's actually failing on the `terraform plan` step with `TF_LOG` output showing that the role is derived from the instance-profile.

wondering if anyone has run into this situation and has any related guidance?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/swipely/iam-docker

Comment: Are you trying to get an instance profile credentialed instance to assume a further role? Because you can't do that. An EC2 instance (or ECS task) can only assume the role they are provided and it must have the correct trust relationship which is different than what IAM users use to assume a role. If you're using environment variables to inject AWS creds for an IAM user then that should work but it's not best practice. It would probably help if you shared exactly what you're trying to achieve and how you're currently doing it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - an ec2 instance profile can assume other roles. You can use [`credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata` in `~/.aws/config`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#using-aws-iam-roles) to do this.

Comment: Yep, that comment is outdated and was in fact outdated when I posted it as I realised later. The `credential_source` thing is reasonably new though. You should consider writing up a longer form answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the special-sauce for my particular use case is Terraform's aws provider [`skip_metadata_api_check` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#skip_metadata_api_check), which apparently inhibits Terraform's behavior around assuming the role of the ec2 instance-profile, and allows it to fallback to it's normal mechanisms for assume-role in my specific setup.

my specific setup involved use of the provider's [`profile` arg](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#profile) in conjunction with the [named profile feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) involving aws shared `credentials` and `config` files.

another option for assume-role in Terraform is the provider's [`assume_role` arg](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#assume_role), but i preferred the more abstracted `profile` option.

> i have also found that use of the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable in conjunction with [the less well documented `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/sessions.html#sessions-with-shared-config) of the AWS Go SDK (used by Terraform) will also works as an alternative, and allows omitting the `profile` argument altogether which may be even more appealing to some

Comment: Do you know why using `skip_metadata_api_check=true` flag works for this? The documentation seems like it would be doing the opposite.